# WPF Binding CommandParameter to GridViewColumnHeader Content from a MenuItem

Tags: wpf, xaml

I guess it is a pretty specific question but I am trying to bind get as `CommandParameter` the `Content` of a `GridViewColumnHeader`. As you will see in the code, it works when I do it in the second setter of the style: `<Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>`. But it does not work for my Menu Items, how sould I bind them? Here is the code:

```
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}}" TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding SortBy}" />
        <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ContextMenu Tag="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=GridViewColumnHeader}}">
                    <MenuItem CommandParameter="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
                                  Header="{UI:Language @{SortAscending}}"
                                  Command="{Binding SortAscending}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what worked for me, a coworker gave me the solution, I was missing a 'DataContext' as My 'GridView' is actualy in a 'ListView':

```
<ContextMenu Tag="{Binding PlacementTarget.CommandParameter, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
             DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

All I did is add a `DataContext` to the `ContextMenu`. hope this helps anyone that might have similar problems.

Answer (score 2):

Bind the `Tag` property to the `PlacementTarget` of the `ContextMenu` itself:

```
<ContextMenu Tag="{Binding PlacementTarget.Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <MenuItem CommandParameter="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
```

Comment: Thanks, tho that was only one of the problems. A coworker gave me the solution, I was missing a 'DataContext' as My 'GridView' is actualy in a 'ListView'.

Comment: Well, the key is still to bind to the PlacementTarget of the ComboBox. Whether you should bind to the DataContext of the PlacementTarget is another thing really.